# ¿Alguien sabe si hay algun problema con mi codigo de conexion a mi base de datos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un sistema de registro, al momento de hacerlo en mi localhost todo funciona perfecto, pero al subirlo a un host gratuito (000webhost) tuve que cambiar los parametros de la conexion y rehacer la base de datos (porque webhost pide que hagas una nueva base de datos en SU pagina y ellos te dan el host, el usuario y la contraseña).

Antes de este insert, tengo otro en donde SI me deja insertar, pero al momento de ejecutar este php siempre me bota al else. Ya comprobe imprimiendo todas las variables y hasta la query y todo se esta guardando, parece ser que no esta conectando el string de conexion.

````
    Sobre todo me gustaria saber si hay mas personas que tiene complicaciones usando este host a la 
    hora de hacer conexiones con BD, sospecho que tal vez son las limitantes del plan gratis:(.

    ```
     <?php  
       $con = new mysqli("localhost","id16743170_root","<)U2cr+ 
                {P{_52YjJ","id16743170_sistemarepau"); 
            

             if (isset($_POST['save_fecha'])){
                                              
                $Lugar = $_POST['Lugar'];
                $Fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
                 $Hora = $_POST['hora'];
                $Tiempo = $_POST['tiempo'];

          $query = "INSERT INTO reservaciones (Lugar,Fecha,Hora,Tiempo) VALUES 
         ('$Lugar','$Fecha','$Hora','$Tiempo')";
          $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

                if ($query_run){                              
                  header("Location: reservas.php");
                    mysqli_close ($con);
               }else{                         
                   echo $query;
                  }
               }

           ?>

    ```
````

Comment: ¿Te arroja algún error?

Comment: Nop, me imprime la query que esta en el else, asi identifico que no esta entrando al if de $query_run

Comment: hola @Esteban coloca el insert directamente en el gestor de base de datos para ver si te hace la inserción y miras que error te aparece